# Unit of measure for $t$ in Exponential Growth Formula

Tags: calculus

In the exponential growth formula, $N = N(0)e^{kt}$, I know that $t$ is for time, but what is the unit of measure?  Years?  Months?  Days?  Hours?

Comment: Depends on the problem, but generally $t$ is dimensionless in the general formula: $N = N_0e^{kt}$.

Comment: Inside the exponential, that should be dimensionless.  So if you want $t$ to be in sec, then $k$ should be in 1/sec.

Answer (score 1):

$$\frac{dN}{dt} = kN$$
That is, the rate of the growth of the population is directly proportional to the number at that instant.

The units of k will determine the units for t.

When solved for N,
$$\frac{dN}{N} = k.dt$$
$$\int_{N_0}^N\frac{dN}{N} = \int_0^t k.dt$$
$$\ln \frac{N}{N_0} = kt$$
$$N = N_0.e^{kt}$$